# Is there an alternate to "omake -P" (server mode)?

Tags: makefile, build-automation, omake

The omake build system has the awesome feature called "server mode", invoked with the command line switch "omake -P". This will cause omake to monitor the file system for any file changes -- when there is a file change it will launch the appropriate build action.

Unfortunately omake does not seem to be actively maintained anymore and the -P feature has severe problems on Ubuntu 12.04. (I can discuss these in some detail if anyone cares).

Does anyone know of a build system like make/omake that has a feature similar to omake -P?

Answer (score 0):

The hard part about this would be defining all the files to watch (Something I assume you have to do with omake anyway).  You could pretty easily write code that watched the files and launched the action.

If I were you, I'd be more inclined to find a really flexible make system and implement the file watching part msyelf.

Problem is, all the build systems I really like are implemented on Java and I'm guessing that's not your cup o' tea (but if you don't mind it, look into gant, should be powerful enough to do anything, and then some)

Comment: So that was the nice think about omake -- it would watch the files that were relevant for the build process (and skip other files in the directories). It is truly a neat feature when it works.